# how to make wordpress header transparent

Tags: css, wordpress

Hello i am working on a wordpress thrive theme "squared", i am trying to make the header of this theme transparent.

i have searched online and tried what i saw, but it still shows up as white instead of transparent.
this is what i have tried

```
header {
    background: transparent;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

this is the site i am trying to make the header transparent

```
http://digitalmarketer.mu/?page_id=65
```

please is there anyone that has been able to overcome such, please help, thanks

Comment: I did not see any property like this in your code. What I see is only a `display: block; text-align: center;` in your main_green.css I think you need to set opacity, don't you? `background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` the last property.

Comment: in the header? when u inspect the element just scroll down

Comment: ok ill try what uv said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the element is showing up as white, it's that what's behind it is white. If you want the transparent menu overlayed over your hero photo, you need to set `header` to `background:transparent;` and set `#floating_menu` to either `position: fixed` or `position: absolute;`.

`position:fixed` is probably the one you want, since you named it "floating menu" (fixed position will keep the menu always at the top of the viewport).

Comment: on fixed and absolute the menu disappears

Comment: I'd assumed when you said you wanted the header to be transparent that this is the look you were going for? http://imgur.com/a/GtxOw

Comment: See above. Set `#floating_menu {position:fixed;}` (make sure that's on `#floating_menu`, not `header`. If you set it on `header`, it does disappear.) Then set `header {background-color:transparent;}`

Comment: PS. It's a bit hard to read, and impossible once you scroll down to the white — you might want to consider doing something like `header {background-color:rgba(52, 52, 52,0.5);}` instead (see here http://imgur.com/a/oMz89).

Comment: here it works, can u please make ur answer above more readable for others who might need it, then i would like it as the answer that has worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to set header's position to absolute so it'll overlay this big entrace image. Try something like that:

```
header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: did u try this before posting it, i mean by inspecting the element cuz it dosent work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can set header to be transparent with this css:
    header {
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: relative;
}

But, you don't have any image under this header, so you will only have whiter header if you do that. So there is no point of making this header transparent since white background is under the header. It would make sense if the main  image that you have goes under your header, but it does not. Your main image is going after the header not under the header. That is why transparent header does not makes any sense.